# How can I fix this purple spot in my photo?

Tags: lightroom, color

As you can see, the peach has a purple spot.

I don't know what happened.

The light is from the right side. I guess that's the place where the light reflected into the lens.

Is there anyway I can fix it using lightroom?

[image]

Comment: You can do the same as @Mike's answer on the blue/purple behind the peach to the left, and also in the lower left corner of the image on the table cloth

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is very easy to fix with most photo editor software.

Here I used Photoshop Elements and the Spot Healing Brush tool to blend out the purple spot.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I just find out how to use lightroom's spot healing tool to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

If you have Adobe Lightroom, try this: zoom in to the purple spot and then select the circular gradient tool. Set a small feather level and make a circular selection of the offending spot. Now carefully adjust the Dehaze option to lessen the impact of the spot. Also try some minor adjustments to the Tint option with the selection still active. The way you adjust both of these controls will depend on the background content of course. This process will not completely clean up the image but will make the spot a lot less noticeable.  Check the before and after using the backslash key.

Answer (score 0):

[image]Yes, the "spot Healing" tool is appropriate for removing unwanted items on an even-toned area. (It can also work on textured areas, but that takes practice.) For example, in the attached image, it would be easy to use the spot healing tool to remove the kite from the sky area, however, the kite string over the rock would be a little tricky, though it could be done carefully.